# Как записать переменную в data ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть:

```
data: '{"id": "'+Cookies.get("id)+'","message": "сообщение"}',
```

Нужно на месте сообщения записать значение из `document.getElementById("chat").value;`

Просто запутался с этими кавычками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: '{"id": "'+Cookies.get("id)+'","message": "'+document.getElementById("chat").value+'"}',
```

Comment: Спасибо большое